# Mern app works perfectly in development mode but says "c.map is not a function" on production mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I have used redux for my mern app and all works perfectly in my local machine. After I deployed it to heroku, it shows error saying that `c.map is not a function`. It points out the error on map method on console in browser.

My react code for that particular error showing component is-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ImageCarousel from '../components/ImageCarousel'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions'
import Loading from '../components/Loading'
import ProductCard from '../components/ProductCard'
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)
  const { loading, products, error } = productList
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
  }, [dispatch])
  return (
    <div className=''>
      <ImageCarousel />
      {loading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <div className='container'>
          <p className='top-picks'>Top picks for you</p>
          <div className='shopping-items'>
            {products &&
              products.map((item) => (
                <ProductCard key={item._id} product={item} />
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

> It is showing error on above products.map line but only in production
> mode.

On redux tools I can clearly see that at first it shows PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS and suddenly it changes to PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL.

> My redux results images are-

[image]

[image]

However in development mode

> For the same request redux result images are-

[image]

Comment: where and how do you dispatch success and fail action?

Comment: check the API which being called. In development, it returns array (as the third image) but in production the API return HTML (first image). But I'm curious why FAILED called after SUCCESS without any more request. Could you provide the code which dispatch SUCCESS and FAILED action?

Comment: @prowse  I messed up during production dude. Now it's working.

Comment: glad its working now